# jquery dynamic checkbox creation with mobile look

Tags: jquery, dynamic, mobile, checkbox, styles

i am in mobile app and i want to create a checkbox list. To do this i use the below code

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    row = resultflatname.rows.item(i);
    if (row.receiptno == 0){
        items.push('<input type="checkbox" name="code_'+ i +'" id="code_'+ i +'" value="' + row.amount + '" previous="' + row.pastpayments + '" barcode="' + row.barcode + '" todayp="' + row.todaypayments + '"/><label for="code_'+ i +'">' + row.period +'..........'+ row.amount+'</label>');
    } else {
    if ((row.receiptno > 0) && (row.amount > row.todaypayments + row.pastpayments)){
        items.push('<input type="checkbox" name="code_'+ i +'" id="code_'+ i +'" value="' + row.amount + '" previous="' + row.pastpayments + '" barcode="' + row.barcode + '" todayp="' + row.todaypayments + '"/><label for="code_'+ i +'">' + row.period +'..........'+ row.amount+'</label>');
    }
}

list.html('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">' + items.join('') + '</fieldset>');
```

and my html

```
<div id="Code" data-role="fieldcontain">
</div>
```

how to refresh this in order to style it with mobile style???

Answer (score 0):

Per the following [jQuery Mobile blog post](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/07/22/jquery-mobile-team-update-week-of-july-18th/), you can trigger the page *create* event to "easily enhance all widgets at once".

```
$(".ui-page").trigger("create");
```

Comment: I am currently using 1.0.1 and it works. I am however using the page id as the selector, not the class (this should not matter). One problem I had was that the markup was not generated when create was triggered (needed to trigger create from my callback).